# How to set total row count and page count in ag-grid pagination in pagination panel from api call

Tags: pagination, ag-grid

I am trying to set the pagination panel numbers with the numbers that is received from api call.
[image]

For instance,I would want to change the ag-26-row-count number with the number i have received from api which is 8000. How to change the total records number.

[image]

Comment: Got any solution?